# Как вычислить сумму не всех элементов в ArrayList, а только одного?

Tags: java-8

Только начала изучать java. Ребята, помогите, пожалуйста. Может кто-то знает как вычислить стоимость автомобилей (поле coast) в ArrayList? Только учусь, так что понять и простить если что(

[image: ![введите сюда описание изображения]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2yGY.png)

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: не "coast", а "price". Совершенно непонятна суть вопроса.

Comment: есть список автомобилей в списке, мне необходимо подсчитать их стоимость

Comment: Вам что-нибудь известно про циклы?

Comment: да, немного читала

Comment: public static int sum() {
        int sum = 0;
        for (Car i : carArrayList)
            sum = sum + i.getCoast();
        return sum;

Comment: Решено. Спасибо